# JavaFX, LineChart get all legends from StackPane

Tags: highcharts, javafx-2, legend, linechart

I have `StackPane` with `LineChart` and every `LineChart` can have several series. 
Using method `getLegend()` I obtain legends only for charts with only one serie. I want to obtain all the series' legends to place them at the bottom. 
Code is the following:

```
    public Node getLegend() {
    HBox hbox = new HBox();

    final CheckBox baseChartCheckBox = new CheckBox(baseChart.getYAxis().getLabel());
    baseChartCheckBox.setSelected(true);
    baseChartCheckBox.setDisable(true);
    baseChartCheckBox.getStyleClass().add("readonly-checkbox");
    baseChartCheckBox.setOnAction(event -> baseChartCheckBox.setSelected(true));
    hbox.getChildren().add(baseChartCheckBox);

    for (final LineChart lineChart : backCharts) {
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(lineChart.getYAxis().getLabel());
        checkBox.setSelected(true);
        checkBox.setOnAction(event -> {
            if (backCharts.contains(lineChart)) {
                backCharts.remove(lineChart);
            } else {
                backCharts.add(lineChart);
            }
        });
        hbox.getChildren().add(checkBox);
    }

    hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hbox.setSpacing(20);
    hbox.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0 10 20 10");

    return hbox;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided it:

```
ObservableList<LineChart> charts = backCharts;
            for (LineChart linechart : charts)  {
                ObservableList<XYChart.Series> serieslists = linechart.getData();
                for (XYChart.Series list : serieslists) {
                    list.getName();
                    }
            }
```